# Speed up network training using Dataset API in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a small dataset that fits nicely in gpu ram.
My goal is to better utilize my gpu (currently around 70%) and thus decrease training time using the new Dataset API in Tensorflow v1.4.

I would like to increase the utilization score of the gpu without adding more layers or increasing the batch size. How is this possible with the Dataset API?

Below is a simplified example of my current implementation:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
import tensorflow as tf
"""
Simple regression example with Dataset API.
The training and val sets are small enought to fit in GPU ram.
"""

TRAIN_SET_SIZE = 130000
VAL_SET_SIZE = 30000

TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 100
VAL_BATCH_SIZE = 1000

TRAIN_PREFETCH = 200
VAL_PREFETCH = 1

INPUT_FEATURES = 120
LAYERS = [500, 500, 500, 500, 1]  # last layer size should be 1


def fc_layer(in_tensor, in_dim, out_dim, name, act_fun=tf.nn.relu):
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        sd = 1.0 / np.sqrt(in_dim)

        W_fc = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], stddev=sd), name='weights')
        b_fc = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([out_dim], stddev=sd), name='bias')

        z_fc = tf.matmul(in_tensor, W_fc) + b_fc
        if act_fun is None:
            return z_fc
        else:
            return act_fun(z_fc)


# Create dummy data
train_set_x = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(TRAIN_SET_SIZE, INPUT_FEATURES)).astype(np.float32)
train_set_y = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=2, size=(TRAIN_SET_SIZE)).astype(np.float32)
val_set_x = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(VAL_SET_SIZE, INPUT_FEATURES)).astype(np.float32)
val_set_y = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=2, size=(VAL_SET_SIZE)).astype(np.float32)

# Reset graph
tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    # Dummy train data
    train_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_set_x, train_set_y))
    # TODO First batch and then prefetch or inverse the order?
    # TODO TRAIN_PREFETCH value?
    train_set = train_set.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).batch(TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(TRAIN_PREFETCH)

    # Dummy val data
    val_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_set_x, val_set_y))
    # TODO VAL_PREFETCH value?
    val_set = val_set.batch(VAL_BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(VAL_PREFETCH)

    # Iterator
    iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_set.output_types, train_set.output_shapes)
    train_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_set)
    val_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(val_set)
    x, truth = iterator.get_next()

    # Build graph
    activations = []
    activations.append(fc_layer(x,
                                INPUT_FEATURES,
                                LAYERS[0],
                                name='fc0'))

    for layer_ix in range(1, len(LAYERS) - 1):
        activations.append(fc_layer(activations[-1],
                                    LAYERS[layer_ix - 1],
                                    LAYERS[layer_ix],
                                    name='fc' + str(layer_ix)))

    activations.append(fc_layer(activations[-1],
                                LAYERS[-2],
                                LAYERS[-1],
                                act_fun=None,
                                name='fc' + str(len(LAYERS) - 1)))

    prediction = activations[-1]

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(truth - prediction))

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step, name='train_step')

    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True),
                                            log_device_placement=True,
                                            allow_soft_placement=True))
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for e in range(1, 6):  # epochs
        epoch_start_time = time()
        # Train set
        sess.run(train_init_op)
        print('\nTrain init op time: %.4f' % (time() - epoch_start_time))
        while True:
            try:
                batch_start_time = time()
                batch_loss, step, _ = sess.run([loss, global_step, train_step])
#                if step % 1000 == 0:
#                    print('Step: %5d Loss: %.2f, Batch Time : %.5f sec' % (step, batch_loss, time() - batch_start_time))
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break
#        print('Epoch time (without computing val set loss): %.2f' % (time() - epoch_start_time))

        # Val set
        sess.run(val_init_op)
        pred_err = np.ndarray([VAL_SET_SIZE])
        ix = 0
        while True:
            try:
                p, t = sess.run([prediction, truth])
                pred_err[ix:ix + VAL_BATCH_SIZE] = p.reshape([-1]) - t
                ix += VAL_BATCH_SIZE

            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                val_loss = np.mean(pred_err ** 2)
                print('Epoch: %2d, Loss: %.2f, Epoch time: %.2f sec' % (e, val_loss, time() - epoch_start_time))
                break
```